# Need Help With Cartoon Eye Rig Rotation

Tags: modeling, rigging

I have made a pair of eyes that have a cartoony shape (with the help of lattices) and have rigged them. The problem is when I  try to move the eye controller, the eye rotation is a bit... weird. I'm attaching the *.blend file along with screenshots

**Edit:** I haven't rigged one of the eyes, so you'll only see one eye move

Blend file

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Modified the .blend file to ad a face. Now if you select the eye controller and press G+Z and move your mouse up/ down, you'll see that the eye movement is weird. I want the eyes to rotate within the lattice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Lattice Object* has its origin point outside the cage, not at the origin of the bone which it's parented to. So all rotations of the bone move the mesh around this origin point, not at its center. To fix this, do the following:

1. Select the *Lattice Object* in *Object Mode*.
2. From the menu, go to *Object* > *Set Origin* > *Origin to Geometry*
3. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected*.
4. Select the eye and the pupil, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> > *Selection to Cursor*.

Comment: Edited the question. I haven't rigged one of the eyes, so you'll only see one eye move

Comment: Also added a new blend file. If you select the eye controller and press G+Z, you'll see the "weird" eye movement. I want the eyes to rotate within the lattice

Comment: Yes, I realized that now. Edited my answer. This should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is:

- Join the pupil to the eye sphere (use a *Shrinkwrap* modifier and apply to make it stick to the round surface)
- Select the armature, in *Edit* mode, put the eye bone in the center of the eye sphere so that they share the same rotation center
- Parent the eye to the bone (select the eye, shift select the armature, switch to *Pose* mode, select the eye bone and parent to bone)
- Create a lattice that contains the eye. Give the eye a *Lattice* modifier, squeeze the lattice in *Edit* mode.

It should work:

[image]